# spring batch embedded database overrides regular datasource

Tags: database, spring, datasource

i'm using mvn + spring batch and have defined 2 beans, both with the same id="datasource"  Only differences are:

1) one is in the test resource dir, and the other isn't.

- src/test/resources/blah.xml
- src/main/resources/blah.xml

2) the one in the test dir is `<jdbc:embedded-database />` and the other is 
`<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">`

Now, when i run my app, it's using the datasource in the test directory.  i don't understand why.  why would it do that if it's in the test dir?  i then experimented a bit and changed the id of the bean in the test dir to "datasourceBlah" and then the app ran fine using the right datasource this time.  What's going on?

thanks alot, and happy turkey day! holla back